# Background color on List Item doesn't work?

Tags: react-native, background-color, listitem, react-native-elements

i am making a list item for the first time and noticed nothing changes if i use this code:

****EDIT!**

```
     import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { ListItem } from "react-native-elements";
import MaterialIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";
import MaterialCommunityIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

export default class ChangePassword extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  accountIcon = () => (
    <MaterialIcons name="account-box" size={35} type="MaterialIcons" />
  );
  changePasswordIcon = () => (
    <MaterialCommunityIcons
      name="textbox-password"
      size={35}
      type="MaterialCommunityIcons"
    />
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ListItem title="Account" leftIcon={this.accountIcon} bottomDivider />
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#007bff" }}>
          <ListItem
            title="Change password"
            leftIcon={this.changePasswordIcon}
            bottomDivider
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why that is and how i can fix this please.

Appreciate it, thank you for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `react-native-elements`. Therefore, you must use the style of that module.

You can use `containerStyle={{backgroundColor:""}}`

If you just want to change the color of the title, `titleStyle={{backgroundColor:""}}`

**Example**

```js
          <ListItem
            title="Change password"
            leftIcon={this.changePasswordIcon}
            bottomDivider
            containerStyle={{backgroundColor:"blue"}}
            titleStyle={{backgroundColor:"red"}}
          />
```

Comment: That didn't work, `<View style={{ backgroundColor: "#007bff", flex: 1 }}>` removes the content of the `ListItem`. The only thing you see is the bottomDivider line. And if i put a container with `flex:1` around it you see the color but it is below the `ListItem` itself. Very weird, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I opened it up in console. And i could change the background see image https://ibb.co/yXVPsWV inside the PadView, but how do i access the PadView

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { Avatar, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'


const CustomList = () => {
    return (
        <View >
            <ListItem bottomDivider containerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#3d3c3a'}} >
                <Avatar
                    rounded
                    source={{uri: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/100/2500/1656.jpg?hmac=gWyN-7ZB32rkAjMhKXQgdHOIBRHyTSgzuOK6U0vXb1w'}}    
                />
                <ListItem.Content>
                    <ListItem.Title style={{fontWeight: '800'}} >Sr.Manager</ListItem.Title>
                    <ListItem.Subtitle ellipsizeMode='tail' numberOfLines={1} >Hello, Welcome to</ListItem.Subtitle>
                </ListItem.Content>
            </ListItem>
        </View>
    )
}

export default CustomList;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```